# Salir del Bucle sin asignar valor

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una tarea de mi curso de DAW, y me encuentro el siguiente problema:

El ejercicio pide que se metan 6 valores correspondientes a las cantidades de ventas diarias de nuestro negocio, empezando en MARTES y acabando en DOMINGO (tened en cuenta que LUNES está cerrado), en el momento que metamos de valor -1 en MARTES el programa finaliza sacando por pantalla la siguiente estructura:

```
JUEVES SABADO SI
```

Día de mayor venta (JUEVES) + Día de Menor venta (SABADO) + si el domingo vendio más que la media semanal (SI).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    double m , x = 0 , j = 0, v = 0, s = 0, d = 0;
    String media, mayor="", menor="";

    while (true) {

        m = sc.nextDouble();

        if (m == -1) {
            break;
        }

        x = sc.nextDouble();
        j = sc.nextDouble();
        v = sc.nextDouble();
        s = sc.nextDouble();
        d = sc.nextDouble();

    }

    if(m>x && m>j && m>v && m>s && m>d) mayor="MARTES"; 
    else if(x>m && x>j && x>v && x>s && x>d) mayor="MIERCOLES"; 
    else if(j>m && j>x && j>v && j>s && j>d) mayor="JUEVES";  
    else if(v>m && v>x && v>j && v>s && v>d) mayor="VIERNES";  
    else if(s>m && s>x && s>j && s>v && s>d) mayor="SABADO";  
    else if(d>m && d>x && d>j && d>v && d>s) mayor="DOMINGO";

    if(m<x && m<j && m<v && m<s && m<d) menor="MARTES"; 
    else if(x<m && x<j && x<v && x<s && x<d) menor="MIERCOLES"; 
    else if(j<m && j<x && j<v && j<s && j<d) menor="JUEVES";  
    else if(v<m && v<x && v<j && v<s && v<d) menor="VIERNES";  
    else if(s<m && s<x && s<j && s<v && s<d) menor="SABADO";  
    else if(d<m && d<x && d<j && d<v && d<s) menor="DOMINGO";



    if (d > (m + x + j + v + s + d) / 6) {

        media = "SI";
    } else {
        media = "NO";
    }

    if (mayor == menor) {

        System.out.println("EMPATE ");

    } else {
        System.out.println(mayor + " " + menor + " " + media);

    }

}
```

Mi problemas es que siempre me sale MARTES como día que menos se vende. Comprobé que saca el valor -1 debido a que se mete ese valor para acabar el ciclo.

Answer (score 5):

Todo apunta a que el siguiente bucle no es correcto:

```
while (true) {

    m = sc.nextDouble();

    if (m == -1) {
        break;
    }

    x = sc.nextDouble();
    j = sc.nextDouble();
    v = sc.nextDouble();
    s = sc.nextDouble();
    d = sc.nextDouble();
}
```

¿Por qué? Básicamente dos motivos:

- Únicamente se puede salir de el cuando `m==-1`, lo cual implica que ya estás sobreescribiendo el valor de `m`.
- Para cada fila de valores (`m`,`x`,`j`,...) no haces **absolutamente nada**. Al llegar la siguiente fila se sobreescriben los resultados anteriores.

Estas dos condiciones juntas dan lugar a lo siguiente: Cuando sales del bucle se empezarán a calcular los extremos del rango... en este caso `m` será **siempre** -1 y el resto de valores se corresponderá únicamente con los de la última fila.

Que `m` sea `-1` tiene implicación en la siguiente línea:

```
if(m<x && m<j && m<v && m<s && m<d) menor="MARTES";
```

Para verlo más claro:

```
if(-1<x && -1<j && -1<v && -1<s && -1<d) menor="MARTES";
```

Es decir, presumiblemente `-1` será menor que el resto de valores.

Otro aspecto raro que veo es que estás manejando `int` en vez de `double`. Las variables deberían ser, por tanto, de tipo `int` para evitar problemas en las comparaciones:

```
int m , x = 0 , j = 0, v = 0, s = 0, d = 0;

m = sc.nextInt(); // Y sucesivos...
```

Para simplificar las cosas deberías plantearte usar un array para almacenar los valores:

```
int[] valores = new int[6];
```

De tal forma que el índice 0 almacenará el valor del martes, el 1 para el miércoles, ... Bien, rellenar el array se podría hacer así:

```
while (true) {

    int valor = sc.nextInt();

    if (valor == -1) {
        break;
    }

    valores[0] = valor; // Valor del martes

    for( int = 1; i<valores.length; i++) // Resto de la semana
      valores[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Y para saber los elementos mayor y menor:

```
int minIdx = 0;
int maxIdx = 0;

for( int i=1; i<valores.length; i++ )
{
  if( valores[minIdx] > valores[i] ) minIdx = i;
  if( valores[maxIdx] < valores[i] ) maxIdx = i;
}
```

Ahora ya tienes en `minIdx` el índice con menor valor y en `maxIdx` el índice que posee el valor más alto. Con estos datos sacar los textos podría ser trivial:

```
String[] nombres = {"MARTES", "MIERCOLES", "JUEVES", "VIERNES", "SABADO", "DOMINGO" };

System.out.println(nombres[maxIdx] + " " + nombres[minIdx] + " " + media);
```

---

**Solución sin arrays**

Bucle de captura

```
while (true) {

    int valor = sc.nextInt();

    if (valor == -1) {
        break;
    }

    m = valor; // Valor del martes
    x = sc.nextInt();
    j = sc.nextInt();
    v = sc.nextInt();
    s = sc.nextInt();
    d = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Clase de utilidades para no repetir código

```
class Utils
{
  public static String GetDiaSemana(int valor, int m, int x, int j, int v, int s, int d)
  {
    if( valor == m )
      return "MARTES";
    else if( valor == x )
      return "MIERCOLES";
    else if( valor == j )
      return "JUEVES";
    else if( valor == v )
      return "VIERNES";
    else if( valor == s )
      return "SABADO";

    return "DOMINGO";
  }
}
```

Detección del mayor y el menor

```
int minIdx = 0;
int maxIdx = 0;

int valorMin = min(min(min(min(min(m,x),j),v),s),d);
int valorMax = max(max(max(max(max(m,x),j),v),s),d);

String menor = Utils.GetDiaSemana(valorMin,m,x,j,v,s,d);
String mayor = Utils.GetDiaSemana(valorMax,m,x,j,v,s,d);

System.out.println(mayor + " " + menor + " " + media);
```

Comment: Esta bien la solución, el problema es que no podemos usar arrays.

Comment: @IvanVL He editado la respuesta. El código no está compilado porque no tengo compilador a mano ahora mismo, pero entiendo que debería funcionar.